Equivariant Chow groups
I am new to algebraic geometry. I am reading about equivariant Chow groups from the paper "equivariant intersection theory" by Edidin and Graham. I was trying to calculate some basic equivariant Chow groups My question is the following:

Let $X=\operatorname{Spec} K$ and $G$ be a finite group. Consider $G$ as a group scheme. Then dimension of $G$ is 0. According to the paper to calculate it we have to tale a $l$ dimensional $G$ representation $V$ an d an open set $U$ of $V$ on which $G$ acts freely. (I am a bit confused here that in which topology the open set is!) Then $\operatorname{CH}^G_i(X)=\operatorname{CH}_{i+l}(U/G)$. How to calculate usual Chow groups of $U/G$?

In particular if we take $G$ to be cyclic group and the action of $G$ on $V$ by rotations such that no point except origin is fixed then we can take $U$ to be $V-0$ and in that case $U/G$ is a cylinder. Then how to get chow groups of that?


Thanks in advance.

It’s the Zariski topology, and calculating Chow groups is famously complicated. You can read Fulton’s Intersection Theory to get a sense of the available tools. You might want to do that before learning about equivariant Chow groups. Also, saying “$U/G$ is a cylinder” does not actually describe the quotient as a scheme.

A good exercise is to do the case of the $B\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ explicitly, using the action on $\mathbb{A}^n$ by multiplication by $\pm 1$.

@SamirCanning In this case $CH_i ^{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}(B\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) = CH_{i+l}(\mathbb{A}^n  \times U/(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}))$. Now at this point I am stuck.

I mean that you should take $\mathbb{A}^n = V$, and then figure out what the open set $U$ should be, and what the quotient is explicitly. I would do the cases $n=1$ and $n=2$ first.
